# How to spawn really parallel tasks on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

Sorry, my first question here. I'm not sure to be the first to ask this, but I could not find answers anywhere.

Modern CPU are heavily multi-threaded/cored but Linux does not garantee processes/threads to physically run in the same time (time sharing).
I'd like my (C++) programs to take advantage of this hardware: spawn small tasks (to update a Hash, copy a data) while going on with the main thread. The goal is to run the program faster. As it does not make sense to spawn a 500ns task and to wait 1ms for its execution I'd like to be (almost) sure that the task will be really executed in the same time as the main thread.

I could not find any paper or discussion on this subject, but I'm not sure to search properly, I just don't know how this thing would be named.
Could someone tell me:
- what's the name of such parallel (same time) executions ?
- is this possible on Linux (or which kind of OS offer such service) ?

Thanks

Comment: You are correct. It doesn't make sense to spawn a process or thread for a very short task. A "Thread Pool" <--search keyword may help you here as the threads are already up and running and waiting for a job. This eliminates the spawning time, but not time lost scheduling the thread or messaging the thread. What it does help with is allowing a bucket of short tasks to be queued up and process withing whatever timeslice the thread may have, and if the size of your thread pool matches the number of physical cores you may see some decent gains.

Comment: Guaranteed same-time execution is mostly found in embedded realtime operating systems where you carefully control thread scheduling. It's not found in standard Linux because it makes programs run more slowly (by having to wait for N free cores instead of just running immediately), while providing no useful benefits.

Comment: Thanks. Yes in case of a pool of threads I still have to hope that my threads are scheduled immediately, which basically means the computer has nothing else to do (unlikely). I find strange that on Linux there is no way to have at least two threads running physically in the same time.

Comment: I understand it's not a good idea to prevent scheduling of a process if N physical threads are not available, but it'd be nice to say "I'd need N threads, give me what you can". It'd also be good for caches, if threads were all scheduled on the same core.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my question was more OS than programming oriented, and that I should ask it on a more appropriated Programmers site, here:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/325257/possiblity-to-request-several-linux-threads-scheduled-together-in-the-same-time

Thanks for answers, they made me advance and better define what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is cpu thread affinity and cgroups under Linux.  There is a lot of complexity to it and you will need to experiment with your particular requirements.

A common strategy in low latency applications is to assign a CPU resource solely to a particular process or thread. The thread runs 'hot' thereby never releasing the CPU to any other process including the kernel.

The Reactor pattern is useful for this model.  A queue is setup on a hot thread with other threads feeding the queue.  The queue itself can be a bottleneck but thats a whole other discussion.  So in your example, the main (hot?) thread will be writing events into the queue of other hot worker threads.  Some sort of rendezvous event will indicate to the main thread that the worker threads are finished.

This strategy is only useful for CPU bound applications.  If your application is I/O bound then the kernel will likely do a better job than a custom algorithm.

To directly answer your question, yes this is possible in Linux with C/C++ but it is not trivial.

I have some old articles on my blog that may be of interest.

http://matthewericfisher.tumblr.com/post/6462629082/low-latency-highly-scalable-robust-systems

--Matt

Comment: Thanks Matt. You got the point. I've read you blog post. So you are saying it'd possible to assign a CPU resource exclusively to a thread, being a user ? Yes I'm talking about CPU bound cases. I'd like to dig deeper please. There are few problems I did not talk about. 1. My applications run on grid (batch) systems. It's very unlikely I, as a user, would be allowed to have such a low level control on the grid. While if I could tell: "try to schedule these two threads in the same time on the same CPU" (different from anchoring to a particular CPU as in affinity) it'd be certainly accepted. ...

Comment: 2. I wonder if with the current linux scheduler (which splits allocated CPU time when clone() is executed) there is still any benefit in fine-grain parallel execution (I mean there are sequential dependencies after a short laps of time) on grid systems where you don't control nodes' load. I guess my code would run faster on not loaded machines but run even slower (compared to not parallel version) on fully loaded machines. In which case I'd have to use parallel processes (to request more CPU time) and talk through shared mem, but would still have the "same time exec" problem.

Comment: Alpa,  The thread affinity features of Linux do require elevated privilege to setup the groups.  I believe that once a normal user is part of a group then migrating threads in/out of the group is non-privileged.  It has been awhile since I set up a cgroup.  A particular CPU can be associated to multiple threads/processes as well. In this case the kernel scheduler will take over as usual but with the smaller set of tasks.

Comment: I'm trying to build my reputation on Stack Overflow.  If my answer was helpful please accept it.  Thanks

Comment: I voted for but I'm newbie here so the system does not show it.

Comment: The doc says: "A thread's CPU affinity mask determines the set of CPUs on which it is eligible to run.". It says nothing about the scheduling time. This is basically the comment I made to answer one. I'd like to pair physical execution time of threads. Affinity would work if I was allowed to forbid scheduling of other users threads on "my" CPUs, which is impossible, especially of computation grids.